# ASP.NET Core 2 AuthenticationSchemes

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

There are several authentication schemes but I can't find any documentation on them. How do they differ?

```
options.DefaultScheme
options.DefaultChallengeScheme
options.DefaultForbidScheme
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme
options.DefaultSignInScheme
options.DefaultSignOutScheme
```

Comment: Did you read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme)?

Comment: I can't find any information about subject there.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/aspnet/announcements/issues/262)

- **DefaultScheme**: if specified, all the other defaults will fallback to
  this value
- **DefaultAuthenticateScheme**: if specified,
  AuthenticateAsync() will use this scheme, and also the
  AuthenticationMiddleware added by UseAuthentication() will use this
  scheme to set context.User automatically. (Corresponds to
  AutomaticAuthentication)
- **DefaultChallengeScheme** if specified,
  ChallengeAsync() will use this scheme, [Authorize] with policies that
  don't specify schemes will also use this
- **DefaultSignInScheme** is used
  by SignInAsync() and also by all of the remote auth schemes like
  Google/Facebook/OIDC/OAuth, typically this would be set to a cookie.
- **DefaultSignOutScheme** is used by SignOutAsync() falls back to DefaultSignInScheme
- **DefaultForbidScheme** is used by ForbidAsync(),
  falls back to DefaultChallengeScheme

So, you specify, which [authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/understanding-http-authentication), is used in corresponding methods in `IAuthenticationService`

Comment: Holy cow, this helped me solve an issue I've had for months. I feel a little stupid now. I had API key auth setup on an internal API, and I really needed kerberos as well. Just setting the `DefaultScheme` to kerberos worked like a charm - now it looks for the API key first, but then falls back to kerberos if that fails. Today, you are my hero just for quoting documentation.